# VBA for-loop with base 2 increment

Tags: vba, for-loop

For identifying the contents of a bitmask value I need an efficient VBA solution to iterate through the possibilities (1, 2, 4, 8, .. skipping anything in between)

Right now my only solution is to iterate through the whole range and check if the current iteration is a base 2 number

```
For i = ErrorType.[_First] To ErrorType.[_Last]
  If isBase2(i) Then
    ...
  End If
Next i
```

I was thinking of something along the lines of this Java code snippet

```
for(int i = 0; i < x; i = Math.pow(2, i++)) {
  ...
}
```

but I have not been able to replicate this in VBA yet without causing endless loops.

Comment: 0 isn't a power of 2.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett Certainly, oversight with the description. The actual bitmask does not include 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim pow As Long
Dim i As Long
For pow = -1 To 4 'or however high you want to go
    If pow = -1 Then
         i = 0 ' Special case: 0 isn't a power of 2
    Else
         i = 2 ^ pow
    End If
    Debug.Print i
Next pow
```

Answer (score 0):

In java, think more along the lines of `for (int i = 1; i <= x; i <<= 1)`.

That way, if we try to translate that to vba and keep in mind that there is no shifting in vba, we could arrive at something like this by reforming the same logic into a while loop with multiplication:

```
Dim i As Integer
i = 1

Do While i <= x
    i = i * 2
Loop
```

I would keep in mind that pow is fairly expensive just for finding powers of two. Just handle 0 as a separate case before the loop and avoid all comparisons. VBA isn't the most efficient of platforms anyway, so keeping it simple is usually the way to go.